# How to use a key array to remove specific items from a main array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

First of all thank you to whoever reads this whole question. I am having trouble writing a function that can take a key array and use the indices to remove like items from a main array.

My main Array

```
var mainArray = [
    {fruit:"apple",color:"red"}, 
    {fruit:"orange",color:"orange"}, 
    {fruit:"banana",color:"yellow"}, 
    {fruit:"apple",color:"red"}, 
    {fruit:"banana",color:"yellow"},
    {fruit:"mango",color:"greenishyellowishred"}
]
```

Array of items will be added to this `mainArray` and I need to remove multiple items at a time.

My key Array

```
var keyArray = [{fruit:"apple",color:"red"}, {fruit:"banana",color:"yellow"}]
```

I am attempting to remove the `"apple"` and the `"banana"` by using a for loop to decrement through the array to maintain the integrity of the `mainArray`.

```
 for(var i = mainArray.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    for(var j = keyArray.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {     
      if(mainArray[i].fruit === keyArray[j].fruit) {
        mainArray.splice(i, 1)
        keyArray.splice(j, 1)
      }
    }
 }
```

My issue comes when I am trying to read `mainArray[i].fruit` if i = 0

Thanks in advance for any help possible.

Comment: there is no recursion in the above code

Comment: is the idea that any fruit object that exists in the `keyArray` must be removed from the `mainArray`?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Your code appears to work just fine.

Comment: FYI, if you have the option to alter the structure of your `keyArray` you could make your code more efficient by having it just contain the `fruit` name (ie. `["apple", "banana"]`). Then you could just use `keyArray.indexOf(mainArray[i].fruit) >= 0` rather than needing a second loop.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Your function is working.

Comment: I am attempting to replace my actual values with the fruit objects. My error come in the condition of the if statement. It says that I am not able to read the property of the array at index 0.

Comment: my original code:
        for(var i = epc.po.itemArray.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
              for(var j = items.length - 1; j > -1; j--) {
                 if(epc.po.itemArray[i].item === items[j].item) {
                   epc.po.itemArray.splice(i, 1)
                   items.splice(j, 1)
                 }
               }
            }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```js
var mainArray = [
    {fruit:"apple",color:"red"}, 
    {fruit:"orange",color:"orange"}, 
    {fruit:"banana",color:"yellow"}, 
    {fruit:"apple",color:"red"}, 
    {fruit:"banana",color:"yellow"},
    {fruit:"mango",color:"greenishyellowishred"}
];
var keyArray = [{fruit:"apple",color:"red"}, {fruit:"banana",color:"yellow"}];
var tempArray = [];
for(let j = 0; j < keyArray.length; j++) {
  for(let i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) { 
    if(mainArray[i].fruit === keyArray[j].fruit) {
      tempArray.push(mainArray[i]);
    }
  }
}
mainArray = mainArray.filter( function( el ) {
  return !tempArray.includes( el );
});
console.log(mainArray);
```